# Using codeigniter and Rackspace Cloud Files with ORD data center

Tags: php, codeigniter, rackspace, cloudfiles

I'm using a library I found here:
https://bitbucket.org/modomg/codeigniter-rackspace-cloudfiles/

To upload some stuff from my site to cloud files. I have the container in the DFW center, but my cloud sites is hosted in ORD. I want them to be in the same data center. Everything works fine when I use the container in the DFW data center, but when I make a new container and put it in the ORD data center and try using that it isn't working. Has any one had this problem? What needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

This was brought to my attention recently. I worked on this for a while today and it looks like the older version of rackspace isn't compatible with the ORD datacenter or their latest versions of the API. I'm still looking into this, but I might have to rewrite the library with the new code that they've recently published. Currently it only works for DFW.

Keep an eye on the repo and the issue log for more changes coming up. I know a lot of people use this library so I want to make sure that it continues to work for everyone. Sorry I couldn't be of more help at the moment. Please contact me if you need anything else in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the v1 auth api only gives back one storage url.  the v2 auth api gives back all endpoints but isn't a simple conversion from the existing header based v1 auth.  a hack that could be done is to change the storage url datacenter from dfw1 to ord1.